# AR model throws ValueError on a constant time series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, python, autoregressive, statsmodels

Here's my code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AR


model = AR(np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))
model = AR(arr)
results = model.fit(method='mle', maxlag=10)
model.predict(results.params)
```

The error I'm getting:

> ValueError: x contains a constant. Adding a constant with trend='c' is
>   not allowed.

Why can't the AR model deal with a constant series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACF is the ratio between the covariance and the variance ..If the variance is zero the ACF is inestimable as the covariance is also zero.

If the variance is zero the ar(1) coefficient is zero AND is redundant to the estimated mean yielding a standard error of 0. .

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!